# Android studio - mediaPlayer

Tags: java, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I'm doing a project on Android Studio and I've got a problem:

I have changed the volume of the media in one activity and I've tried to move the media to the second activity.

I've succeded to move the audio to the second activity but it was without any volume change...

How can I fix it?

update:
Hi, because I can't save the changes that I have made in my mediaPlayer I decided to record the song before I moving between the activitys.

I got a problem with the mediaRecorder - I can't start recording and I have no idea what is wrong in my code...

my code:

```
rec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(secondRemix.this, "You are starting the recording, you need to wait a little bit until it will be ready.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageState()+"/tempRecord.3gpp";
            record.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            record.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            record.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            record.setOutputFile(FILE);
            record.start();//check it!!!
            song.start();
            startActivity(new Intent(secondRemix.this,waitScreen.class));
            record.stop();
            record.release();
```

can anybody help me with that? –

Thank you!

Comment: In other words you want to change Activity without stopping audio?

Comment: About posting the code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: no, its not what I mean...

Comment: I want to change activity with the changed settings that I did to the media...

Answer (score 0):

Is not a properly answer but might help. Short: you can't.

Why?

The native Media Player uses canvas to render the frames and it is automatic cleaned when is not on the screen.

**Workaround 1:** When you start the video on the new Activity automatically start from the position that the user stopped.

**Workaround 2 (*Like Youtube*):** Use fragments to manage your view.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!
I wrote an update to my question, can you answer to that?
thank you!

Comment: I cant start the recording, a compilation problem.

Comment: Do you want to record the screen while a video is playing?

Comment: or answers below